# Architecture of wso2 DAS Dashboard

Tags: wso2, dashboard, complex-event-processing

I want to know where my dashboard takes information from. Where is this information stored, in files or RDBMS?

I want change the WSO2 dashboard to TABLEU instead. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It loads data from the persisted data from default H2 database. You can change data source to store in RDBMS data bases such as My SQL [1] and then connect tableau to that specific data source.

Real time data it will not store just push to the dashboard, you can push real time data to same RDBMS event publisher by using same RDBMS data source.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Datasources

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/RDBMS+Event+Publisher